# Defined a protocol in a Framework, but its not accessible from the different project

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I have created a protocol inside a framework, Following is my code for Framework.

```
public protocol CodairaProtocols{
    
    func onOTPGenerated()
    func onResendOTP()
    func onVerifyOTP()
}
```

[image]

After that i created a new project, and drag, dropped this framework to it.

I can create the instance of `CodairaAuth`,and use it inside the new project,  but when i try to use `CodairaProtocols`, it says that `Cannot find type 'CodairaProtocols' in scope`

I tried to clean and rebuild the project, but the issue is still there.

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding the needed `import` statement?

Comment: Could be a red herring. Try to do this: in the *app*: go to `import [YourFramework]` statement on top, and Command+Click on it. It will show you the framework the way app sees it. So you can see if the `CodairaProtocols` is even there. if not - something is wrong with framework setup (but your protocol definition is fine, so it's something else). If it's there, then something is wrong with your App setup

Comment: @HangarRash : Yes

Comment: @rapiddevice : Its only creating problems with a protocol, if i create multiple classes, all of them are usable from the other project.